# New with ruby. Id and quantity of item

Tags: ruby

I'm new to ruby, and I'm trying to edit others scripts made in ruby to figure out how it works. Now, I was struggling for days with this one. I have a script with the next command:

```
def has_card_in_deck?(id)
  actor = $game_actors[$game_variables[27]]
    for card in actor.deck
      return true if card.id == id
    end
  return false
end
```

This return me if there's a card with the said ID in the actor deck. It works perfectly. But I tried to create a second command with the almost exact question, but instead of return me if there's a card with certain ID, I want to confirm if there's 2 or more copies of that ID card. I can't figure out how to ask the quantity of the object "card". I tried putting (* 2) with the ID, but of course, this will just ask if there's a card with the double value of the id input.

Comment: This was written by someone who doesn't know Ruby. Almost nobody in Ruby uses `for` statements, `return` is relatively uncommon, and that function is rife with (unnecessary) global variables. It looks like a Java programmer read the first page of a Ruby tutorial, figured "yeah, I got this", and stopped reading. Find a different guide.

Comment: Speaking of better guides - here's one for the [count function](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ruby-enumerable-count-function/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting a Count of Array Items that Meet a Certain Criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10824679/getting-a-count-of-array-items-that-meet-a-certain-criteria)

Comment: If one only needs to know if something matches a criteria _at least_ a certain amount of times, it may be worthwhile to implement a `occurs_at_least_times(n) { |x| ... }` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `#count` in of Array.
For example,

```rb
nums = [1,2,2,3,4,5]
nums.count { |num| num == 2 }
=> 2
nums.count { |num| num >= 3 }
=> 3
```

So you can write a has_at_least_2_cards?(id)

```rb
def has_at_least_2_cards?(id)
  actor = $game_actors[$game_variables[27]]
  actor.deck.count { |card| card.id == id } >= 2
end
```